# Arranging array in ascending order 3

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I'm new to programming and currently stuck at trying to get the output of the program to show in ascending order,

Two arrays is given

```
array1={1,3,5,7}  // odd numbers

array2={2,4,6,8} // even numbers

Output= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

output will be in ascending order. How to write program in java for this output.

Comment: Providing requirements without showing any effort was once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is still [being debated now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic), and many people consider it to be rude.

Comment: put the two arrays into one data structure and use a basic sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two arrays into an `ArrayList` using `addAll` method and sort using `Collections.sort` method

If you want the results to be in array you can use `toArray` method to convert from `ArrayList` to `array`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class MainDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
        Integer[] array2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

        List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        mylist.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
        mylist.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));

        Collections.sort(mylist);

        // Print the sorted list....
        for (Integer x : mylist) {
            System.out.println(x+" ");
        }

        // You can also convert back to array
        Integer[] FinalArray = mylist.toArray(new Integer[mylist.size()]);
        for (int i = 0; i < FinalArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1- A simple solution is to create an output array of size (m+n) and one by one copy all arrays to it. Finally, sort the output array using any O(nLogn) sorting algorithm. This approach takes O((m+n)Log(m+n)) time.

Approach 2-You can merge arrays in O((m+n)*Log(m+n)) time using Mean Heap. Following is detailed algorithm.

1. Create an output array of size (m+n).
2. Create a min heap of size k and insert 1st element in all the arrays into a the heap
3. Repeat following steps (m+n) times.
    a) Get minimum element from heap (minimum is always at root) and store it in output array.
    b) Replace heap root with next element from the array from which the element is extracted. If the array doesn’t have any more elements, then replace root with infinite. After replacing the root, heapify the tree.

Where  m and n are sizes of the two arrays given.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I don't think the level of it is sensible for the question at hand, as the OP says they are new to programming. Any mention of big O may be confusing, although it is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two arrays in one then use `Arrays.sort()`.

```
int array1={1,3,5,7};

int array2={2,4,6,8};
int array[]=new int[10]; //You can change the 10 to max
int len=array1.length+array2.length;
int j=0,k=0;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
     if(j<4)
     array[i]=array1[j++];
     else array[i]=array2[k++];
}
Arrays.sort(array,0,len);
```

**Output**= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Answer (score -1):

Join two arrays :

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;
         import java.util.List;
         public class Main {
         public static void main(String args[]) {
         Int a[] = { 1,2,3 };
          Int b[] = { 4,5 };
           List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
           Object[] c = list.toArray();

    }
 }
```

Arrange one array ascending :

```
             for (int j = 0; j<array.length; j++) {
              for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
                   if (array[j] < array[k]) {
                     int buffer = array[j];
                  array[j] = array[k];
               array[k] = buffer; 
               }
             }
          }
```